# Fit annotations in Watchkit Map with padding

Tags: swift, watchkit, mkmaprect, wkinterfacemap

I can't for the life of me figure this one out. I have been able to get annotations on the map and create a new Rect to hold them and set the map to that rect but my issue is obviously these annotations are right at the very edges of my map and I would like to add some extra space. Here is what they look like currently

[image]

And the code to generate this is

```
...
@IBOutlet var mapOutlet: WKInterfaceMap!
...

// setup a null MpRect
var zoomRect = MKMapRect.null;

// set lat and lon
let lat = data?["latitude"] as! Double
let lon = data?["longitude"] as! Double
let phoneLat = 32.801296
let phoneLon = -79.898318

// create coordinates
let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
let phoneLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: phoneLat, longitude: phoneLon)

// setup location points
let myLocationPoint = MKMapPoint(myLocation)
let phoneLocationPoint = MKMapPoint(phoneLocation)

// setup MapRects
let myLocationRect = MKMapRect(x: myLocationPoint.x, y: myLocationPoint.y, width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
let phoneLocationRect = MKMapRect(x: phoneLocationPoint.x, y: phoneLocationPoint.y, width: 0.1, height: 0.1)

// setup MapRect union
zoomRect = myLocationRect;
zoomRect = zoomRect.union(phoneLocationRect);

mapOutlet.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect)
mapOutlet.addAnnotation(myLocation, with: .red)
mapOutlet.addAnnotation(phoneLocation, with: .purple)
```

Comment: Have you tried the `showAnnotations` method?

Comment: `mapOutlet` is an instance of `WKInterfaceMap` so it doesn't have a `showAnnotations()` method